# PHP preg_replace: [éèêë] vs (é|è|ê|ë)

Tags: php, preg-replace

I want 'é' to become 'e'.

Can someone please explain to me why $mot1 shows 'ee' when $mot2 works fine?

```
$mot="é";
$mot1=preg_replace("/[éèêë]/", "e", $mot);
$mot2=preg_replace("/(é|è|ê|ë)/", "e", $mot);
echo $mot1." ".$mot2;
```

You can test it here: http://phptester.net/

Thanks! :)

Renaud

Comment: Just use the `u` UNICODE modifier. See https://ideone.com/bvXraf

Comment: I couldn't find this previous question. Thanks, Wiktor!